# How to pass a dictionary inside os.system({dict}) as a parameter iin python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, os.system

I have a dictionary with parameters, I want to pass that dic={a:b,c:d,e:f} inside a "os.system" like this "os.system(dic)", but getting error.
when I am passing all the parameters directly inside os.system then it is working perfectly but getting error when passing it from dictionary

Comment: Try: `os.system(**your_dict)` for kwarg unpacking. Please also never re-use names of builtins in your code. So call it something other than `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionnary is a python type and can be declared using the variable type 'dict()' or brackets '{}'

So I think your problem is that you are storing your dictionary contents in a variable called dict, which cannot be used as a name. Try the following for instance:

```
dic = {a:b,c:d,e:f}
```

On the other hand, [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) takes a string as argument, not a dictionary.

Comment: oops sorry I made a mistake I am not using "dict" I just gave an example

Comment: I see. Then you should be fine. See mechanical_meat kwarg unpacking solution for os.system()

Comment: no that doesn't worked as well but I tried something else and that worked for me